# Having problems with Array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sqlite

SO here's my setup.  I have an object called radiostations where I have several strings like callsign, frequency declared and an NSMutableArray called amStationInfo.  On my viewcontroller, I access an SQLite database which populates the an array like so...

radiostations.h

```
@interface radiostations : NSObject {

    NSString *format;
    NSString *city;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *format;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *city;
```

ViewController.m

```
radiostations *amStationClass = [[radiostations alloc] init];
NSMutableArray* amStationInfo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
    NSString *cityField = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                   (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 10)];
    NSString *formatField = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                    (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
    [amStationInfo addObject:amStationClass];
                    [amStationClass setCity:cityField];
                    [amStationClass setFormat:formatField];
    }
[tabView reloadData];
sqlite3_finalize(statement);
```

and then I populate a UITableView

```
NSString *cityValue = [(radiostations *)[amStationInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] city];
NSString *formatValue = [(radiostations *)[amStationInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] format];
cityLabel.text = cityValue;
formatLabel.text = formatValue;
```

Initially I was dealing with a few Arrays and this worked just fine.  I then changed it so that I was only dealing with one array using a class object and now it's not working.  I know the SQLite query and what not works so Im not having any problems with that.  It seems as though the array does not get populated.

Comment: Your naming is a mess; `radiostations` should be `RadioStations`, `amStationClass` should be `amStation` (it isn't a class, it is an instance), `amStationInfo` should probably be `amStationsArray`, `cityField` should be `city` or `cityName`, etc... also, if you aren't using ARC, you'll be leaking two strings, too.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I am quite new and I just realized that.  I am using ARC however.

Comment: No worries;  Objective-C, iOS, Cocoa, and all the frameworks in between are very much built on a whole slew of common patterns.  If you learn those patterns and follow them, it'll make things a whole lot simpler!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are changing the properties of the same `radiostations` object and adding it over and over again to the array. You need to create a new `radiostations` object for each row from your sqlite database and add this:

```
while (...) {
    // fetch data as before

    radiostations *record = [[radiostations alloc] init];
    [record setCity: cityField];
    [record setFormat: formatField];
    [amStationInfo addObject: record];
    [record release];
}
```

If you are using ARC you need to remove the line `[record release];`, otherwise it is necessary to avoid leaking those objects.

Comment: I am using ARC and therefore I am not releasing amStationClass

Comment: It works now, it turns out, I needed to allocate *record inside the while statement and not outside and I added the object into the Array after i set the strings... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

where did you allocate/init your mutablearray?
something like:

```
NSMutableArray* amStationInfo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

you need to allocate it once, before to add objects in it

Comment: I forgot to allocate it, and even though I did, it still does not populate

Comment: i confess i read your question in hurry, when i noticed that error, but probably other are in... what about Sven answer?

Comment: Sven's answer worked.  I changed two things, I allocated the instance inside the while loop and added in into the array after I set the strings.